# ggplot boxplot gives single box instead of several boxes

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have data in this format

```
         Var1 Var2 value
1   uc010ocr.1    1    68
2   uc010ocs.2    1    34
3   uc010oct.2    1     0
4   uc010ocu.2    1  5712
5   uc010ocv.2    1 45674
6   uc010ocw.2    1 46156
7   uc010ocz.2    1 54515
8   uc010oda.2    1     0
9   uc010odb.2    1     0
10  uc010odc.1    1    68
11  uc010odd.1    1 43045
12  uc010ocr.1    2   136
13  uc010ocs.2    2     0
```

The Var2 column goes from 1-10 with each group having the same amount of rows as Var2==1 shown here. The names in Var1 repeat for each Var2 group.

When I do

```
result<-ggplot(datasetMelted, aes(x = Var2, y=value)) + geom_boxplot()+
ggtitle("Coverage")+xlab("Location")+ylab("Coverage")+
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = .9),
size = 6, shape = 4, show_guide = F)
```

I get a single box spanning the x axis. When I replace Var2 with Var1 I get multiple boxes. What am I doing that prevents Var2 from being used as a proper x value? Thanks.

Comment: Use `x = factor(Var2)`

Comment: coolio. Thanks...it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem creating a boxplot and there being was a single box spanning the entire x-axes. I believe it was because my x values were numeric instead of character.

To fix this (and it worked), I converted the column to character with:

```
datasetMelted$Var2 = as.character(datasetMelted$Var2)
```

This should change your Var2 to character form so that it isn't taken into account for the boxplot.